# Разница инициализации объектов С++

Tags: c++, память, инициализация

не могли бы объяснить разницу в инициализации объектов, например:

1. MyClass var(val1, val2);
2. MyClass *var = new MyClass(val1, val2);

Я правильно понимаю, что в первом случае идете выделение памяти из стека, а во-втором из кучи? Какие еще различия того или иного объявления? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вы понимаете неправильно. В первом случае создается объект со статическим (если объявление не в функции) либо с автоматическим временем хранения. Во втором случае создается два объекта: указатель опять со статическим (если объявление не в функции) либо с автоматическим временем хранения и еще один объект с динамическим временем хранения.

Comment: Без пояснения, как время хранения связано со стеком/кучей, это только сбивает новичков с толку (и не только их).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Специально не упоминал стек/кучу чтобы не создавалось впечатление, что они как-то связаны со временем хранения.

Comment: А они связаны. Конечно, c оговорой "если не соптимизировано компилятором".

Comment: Представьте, что к вам на собеседование приходит человек, который мыслит в категориях времени хранения, но не может объяснить их связь со стеком и кучей. Я бы такого не взял: принял бы за того, кто просто зазубрил определения.